# C# replacing items in textfile

Tags: c#

I have a "|" delimited file that all I want to do is read all the lines in it and where "<\HRM>" exists replace it with "" (nothing).  And where "HRM\" exists replace it with ;.  It's got to write out everything in the same order it was read in.

I'd like to do this by just editing the original write, not writing a new one.  If I have to write out a new file then i guess I have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is how big is the file might change the solution or the very least slow it down.

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"YourFilePath", FileMode.Open)))
{
    string fileText = stream.ReadToEnd();

    // Do your replacements
    fileText = fileText.Replace(@"<\HRM>", string.Empty);
    fileText = fileText.Replace(@"HRM\", ";");

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open("@YourFilePath", FileMode.Create)))
    {
        // You do a create because the new file will have less characters than the old one
        writer.Write(fileText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, reading the whole thing in at once? Line-by-line replacement is much easier on your memory usage.

Comment: You are making a couple of assumptions, that A) there are /n/r in the file.  There might not be.  B) that a "</HRM>" or "HRM\" do not wrap lines.  I did not know how the file looked, so the best way would be to read everything in, even if it is slow.  I was going to just read in bytes to a buffer, but how would I know when I was in the middle of a "<\HRM>" or not?

Comment: this worked fine expect it places in an extra space, so it ends up being whatever| ; .  I wneed it to be whatever|;|

the | are already in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write out a new one. There are good reasons for doing this, not the least of which is that it will be much much faster. It will also provide you with a degree of safety with your data (power loss will not result in potential data loss/corruption.

The generally accepted procedure is along the lines of of

- Open new file
- Write out new file
- Move over top of old file

Answer (score 0):

you would have to re-write the file since you will be stripping characters out and thus making it more compact -- unless you wanted to replace your <\HRM> with equivalent spaces to retain position holdings.

String.Replace( "change this", "to this" )